# Is there a way to print all the information received by OSC?

Tags: python, networking, udp, osc

I am a beginner in OSC communication.

I have implemented communication using UDP in the past, but OSC is the first time.

I have read the [Python OSC library documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-osc/).

According to this document, OSC sends certain information to certain URLs such as "/filter".

**OSC_Client.py**

```
import argparse
import random
import time

from pythonosc import udp_client


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--ip", default="127.0.0.1",
      help="The ip of the OSC server")
  parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=5005,
      help="The port the OSC server is listening on")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(args.ip, args.port)

  for x in range(10):
    client.send_message("/filter", random.random())
    time.sleep(1)
```

The code on the receiving side also receives information by specifying a specific URL like "/filter".

OSC_Server.py

```
import argparse
import math

from pythonosc import dispatcher
from pythonosc import osc_server

def print_volume_handler(unused_addr, args, volume):
  print("[{0}] ~ {1}".format(args[0], volume))

def print_compute_handler(unused_addr, args, volume):
  try:
    print("[{0}] ~ {1}".format(args[0], args[1](volume)))
  except ValueError: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--ip",
      default="127.0.0.1", help="The ip to listen on")
  parser.add_argument("--port",
      type=int, default=5005, help="The port to listen on")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
  dispatcher.map("/filter", print)
  dispatcher.map("/volume", print_volume_handler, "Volume")
  dispatcher.map("/logvolume", print_compute_handler, "Log volume", math.log)

  server = osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer(
      (args.ip, args.port), dispatcher)
  print("Serving on {}".format(server.server_address))
  server.serve_forever()
```

However, the code for normal UDP is: It is possible to send a character string without specifying the URL, etc. and receive all the character string information by specifying the port.

Like UDP_Client.py and UDP_Server.py below.

**UDP_Client.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1" 

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    msg = "testSend"
    s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))

s.close()
```

**UDP_Server.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''   
PORT = 5000

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
    print(f"message: {msg}\nfrom: {address}")

s.close()
```

I wonder if there is a way to get all the received data in OSC by specifying only the port number.

I want to analyze the contents of the software that communicates with OSC and know what kind of data is being sent. For that, I want to know if this can be done.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is fire up Wireshark or similar analyzer.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded WireShark. Then I ran the Capture → Start button, but no information about OSC or UDP was displayed. Please tell me how to use this tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing this is an old question, but I stumbled across it looking for help.  If I understand what you were looking to do correctly, you just want to see ALL OSC messages instead of having to specify a path.

If that's the case, the good news is that is easy.

In your OSC_Server.py example, change this:

```
    dispatcher.map("/filter", print)
```

To this:

```
    dispatcher.map("/*", print)
```

This will use the built-in "print()" function to print out all the messages coming in via OSC on whatever port you specify.  A bit surprised the documentation doesn't show this and explain a little better in the examples.

I hope this helps someone